# CSS keep padding for first-child: 0px

Tags: html, css

When a div has `padding-left:10px;` is there a way to make the first child of that div not have a padding-left of 10px;? You'll see in the example below. And no, I cant change anything or add more divs etc.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> New Document </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .root:first-child {
                padding-left:0px;
            }
            .root{
                font-size:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="root" style="padding-left:10px;border: 1px solid black;">
            <div>Root</div> //Padding should not affect this one. How can I do this?
            <div style="border:1px solid black; padding-left:10px;">Folder
                <div style="border:1px solid black; padding-left:10px;">Folder
                    <div>
                        <div>File 1</div>
                        <div>File 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you remove the inline css from parent `.root` or may be just the padding ?

Comment: @joy_S answer is right. here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hYG9s/2/

Comment: @ani Yes I can, I used inline just for this example.

Comment: Then it should be pretty easy. I thought you had inline styling actually.

Comment: @ani In your fiddle, the entire left padding for root is removed. Not just the first child.

Comment: No, I think you are wrong. Padding is there for all other child elements. There is a space between the border and other elements as compared to first div.

Comment: @ani That because the others have left padding as well

Answer (score 4):

Use `div.root:first-child{padding-left:0 !important;}` and then let me know.

You can do this just adding these following CSS:

```
.root{
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:0 !important;
 }
.root div{
   margin-left:10px;
}
.root > div:first-child{
   margin-left:0;
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/AgULeNO/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: This won't work !...Because the parent has inline css. try fiddle.

Comment: `!important` will override it.

Comment: No sir, it'll not. Try fiddle.

Comment: It appear that the entire padding for root is removed. I'm trying to remove the padding for only the first div. The one that has the word root

Comment: There is another way, if it is possible you can add the inline styling for the `<div>Root</div>`.

Comment: `<div style="padding-left:0 !important;">Root</div>` let me know if it works. May be I have another solution also.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a fiddle. Please check it. I think this is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> New Document </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .root:first-child {
    padding-left:0px;
    }
    .root>div:first-child{
         border: 1px solid red;
         width: 500px;
         height: 200px;
    }

    .root{
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size:20px;

    }
    .root div:second-child(2) {
        padding-left:10px;

    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

   <div class="root">
    <div>Root</div> //Padding should not affect this one. How can I do this?
    <div style="border:1px solid black; padding-left:10px;margin-left: 10px;">Folder
        <div style="border:1px solid black; padding-left:10px;">Folder
            <div>
                <div>File 1</div>
                <div>File 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

     </body>
    </html>
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skWR3.png
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the div below the text "Padding should not affect etc." it's not 10px from the border, It's on the border.

Comment: Hi! Use this html as well as css Which I have posted!It will work 100%.

Comment: Here I use width, height and border of the first div to clear exactly

Comment: If you want away so use margin-left instead of padding.

Comment: You can see that I added additional rule  <div style="border:1px solid black; padding-left:10px;margin-left: 10px;">

Comment: Tell me is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the child also

```
.root div:first-child {
    padding-left:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change the padding. But you can try to move that div to the left by 10px to accomplish the same result.

Try

```
.root:first-child {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

or

```
.root:first-child {
    left: -10px;
    position: relative; //you may need to add this
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's what you can do: Now I am assuming all the padding is not inline. I am not completely certain if this is what you want though. But here's my two cents.

http://jsfiddle.net/hYG9s/4/

**CSS**

```
div.root > div:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}    
div.root > div > div{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You fiddle looks the same :) No changes.

Comment: I removed your inline padding, and then added the padding in css. Can you explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Ok. Look, the div under the text `//Padding should not affect this one. How can I do this?` should be 10px away from the border. In short, the div root should have a padding of 10px, but only the div <div>Root</div> should not have a 10px padding. That's the first child right?